# Matrix creation using two variables

Tags: matlab

i have two variable `jmp` (values goes from `1` to `3`) and `dsp` (goes from `a` to `c`). I want to create a matrix say called `path` that will have `dsp` as first column and jmp as second. how can i create that using matlab.

Comment: What is the type of your arrays? Do they hold numerical values or anything? Could you give an example and what are you expecting please? And also what you have tried so far...

Comment: jmp holds integer values and dsp hold strings.

Comment: A matrix can contain only numbers, not characters. You could use a cell array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your purpose is to combine them to serve as paths, you don't need to put them into separate columns. Instead, you can combine them together as a whole. Simple and sufficient.

```
jmp = [1;2;3];
dsp = ['a';'b';'c'];

path = cat(2,dsp,num2str(jmp));
```

After this, `path` will be:

```
a1
b2
c3
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess like this:

```
jmp = [1;2;3]
dsp = ['a';'b';'c']

cat(2,mat2cell(jmp, ones(size(jmp))), mat2cell(dsp,ones(size(dsp))))
```

But I would hope that there is a cleaner way